# How would you show cloth specific information in the user interface

Tags: user-interface

School going kids wear a certain uniform on respective days within a week.

*(e.g. for boys = White half pant, white shirt, tie of a certain color, belt ..)
(e.g. for girls = blue checked frock, navy blue pinafore, black shoes with navy blue socks and belt). They will have different variations to wear on different days.*

What would be a good way to show such information in the user interface for boys / girls. Can you point me to any sites which depict such information very clearly.

Comment: What is the purpose of the application?

Comment: Kids or parents can come to this page, to view what uniform they need to wear on a particular day.

Comment: I'm glad my children don't go to such a school. The prospect of having to worry about different uniforms for each day does not sound appealing.

Comment: It wouldn't change on a daily basis. A student wears the regular uniform on 4/5 days, they usually wear a white uniform on the last date. If the student participates in extra curricular activities (say Scout), they might have a different dress on that date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

How about this kind of table, replace smiley's with uniform images and Description of the uniform below that.

Answer (score 10):

Show the uniforms graphically through images of a boy and a girl wearing the correct uniform for the selected day of the week. If you want to go all out, you could have 360 degree views (spinnable by mouse/gesture) for the boy and girl.

Comment: You had me right up to the point of "360 degree views". That is a total waste of effort (YAGNI). A simple frontal picture with added text would be more than enough.

Comment: @paxdiablo I did say "If you want to go all out". If the dress code is really that complex, this feature may be justified. Otherwise, probably just a frontal view would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Photo and text. It's absolutely enough for parents. May be not enough for designer...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me to be over-complicated to have a "uniform" that changes on a daily basis, to the point that you require an app which informs people what to wear.  But given the requirements, I'd simply show the list of items for each day.

If, for example, there are only a couple combinations, I'd give each combination a name and put the combination name on the calendar.  Then I'd make the name itself a link to further information about it, including the detailed list of clothes and pictures of each item.  Perhaps a picture of a model wearing the clothes but that might not be necessary.

If the uniform varies a lot, such that enumerating the combinations is impractical or impossible, I'd show the full list (with pictures) for each day.

Aside, is this an actual requirement for a real school? My high-school had a uniform and it wasn't nearly so complicated.  There was just a list of allowable/required elements and it was distributed to the parents before the start of the school year.  Most of the time the rules could be stated in a couple sentences, such as "From the start of the school year until October 1st, and from Easter until the end of the school year, the 'Summer Uniform' may be worn; the rest of the school year only the standard uniform is permissible.  The standard uniform is ... for boys and ... for girls.'  This certainly was straightforward enough that there was never any serious question, and if there was a problem the teachers would simply inform the students that they were "out of uniform".